# How to make zoom in/out stay at final position

Tags: android, xml, animation

Zoom in/out animation resets the object shape's after finished. Is there some way to make it stay at its final shape? I got this for now:

```
 <scale android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="10"
        android:toYScale="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimationSet` has a `fillAfter` property which applies the ending value after the animation ends.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true">
   <scale android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="10"
        android:toYScale="10" />
</set>
```